# Filter channel entries by category with nested condition

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I am using EE 2.7.2. How can we filter channel entries like below:

```
{exp:channel:entries category="1&2&3&(5|6)"}
```

Is it possible to use '&' and '|' together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unforchently you can't use '&' and '|' together. In [category parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category) you can use or '&' logic or '|' logic.

*possible solution:*

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT group_concat(entry_id separator ', ') as result_ids FROM
exp_category_posts WHERE entry_id IN 
(SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = 1 AND cat_id = 2 AND cat_id = 3)
AND (cat_id = 5 OR cat_id = 6)" parse="inward"}
  {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{result_ids}"}
    ...
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:query}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Ok Cary, using select query it should work.